# Trouble running GDAL (High Sierra, 10.13.2)

Tags: macos, gdal

I am having a hard time running GDAL in my macOS, running High Sierra, version 10.13.2. I installed it using homebrew and initially, it gave an error that `osgeo` not found. But I did another `easy_install` and now the osgeo error is gone and now it throws this error:

```
> gdal_polygonize.py my_png.png -f "ESRI Shapefile" mylayer.shp

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/gdal_polygonize.py", line 36, in <module>
    from osgeo import gdal
  File "/Users/name/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/GDAL-3.1.0-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/osgeo/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Users/name/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/GDAL-3.1.0-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/osgeo/__init__.py", line 31, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_gdal')
  File "/Users/name/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named _gdal
```

Any help? Thanks!